# Modified Method

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365

I need to write a modify method.

There is field : *LineViewHeader_AccountType*; string; with possible values: Internal, Customer, Tenant

Depending on which value is selected, it is necessary to list the values ​​in the field: *LineViewHeader_AccountNum*

Currently it lists all values in AccountNum, no matter what is selected into in AccountType.

```
[Control("ComboBox")]
class LineViewHeader_AccountType
{
    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public boolean modified()
    {
        boolean ret;

        ret = super();

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly you need to filter lookup for AccountNum based on the value of AccountType. Please check the following link http://thinkinginax.blogspot.com/2018/04/creating-lookup-control-in-d365.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set LineViewHeader_AccountType control value as range:

```
[FormControlEventHandler(formControlStr(PMCContractDetails, 
LineViewHeader_AccountNum), FormControlEventType::Lookup)]
public static void LineViewHeader_AccountNum_OnLookup(FormControl sender, 
FormControlEventArgs e)
{
    Query                   query = new Query();
    QueryBuildDataSource    queryBuildDataSource;
    SysTableLookup          sysTableLookup;
    FormRun                 formRun;
    FormControl             formCtrl;


    formRun = sender.formRun();
    formCtrl = formRun.design().controlName(formControlStr(PMCContractDetails, LineViewHeader_AccountType));

    sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(PMCContract), sender);
    queryBuildDataSource = query.addDataSource(tableNum(PMCContract));
    queryBuildDataSource.addRange(fieldNum(PMCContract, AccountType)).value(queryValue(formCtrl.valueStr()));

    sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(PMCContract, AccountType), true);
    sysTableLookup.addLookupMethod(tableMethodStr(PMCContract, AccountNum));

    sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
    sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[FormControlEventHandler(formControlStr(PMCContractDetails, LineViewHeader_AccountNum), FormControlEventType::Lookup)]
public static void LineViewHeader_AccountNum_OnLookup(FormControl sender, FormControlEventArgs e)
{
    Query                   query = new Query();
    QueryBuildDataSource    queryBuildDataSource;
    SysTableLookup          sysTableLookup;

    sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(PMCContract), sender);
    queryBuildDataSource = query.addDataSource(tableNum(PMCContract));

    sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(PMCContract, AccountType), true);
    sysTableLookup.addLookupMethod(tableMethodStr(PMCContract, AccountNum));

    sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
    sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();       
}
```

Comment: Check @Aliaksandr Maksimau's answer, your answer is missing the query criteria to filter the data in table `PMContract`.